# Having "Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header" even I have set up "allow-from" header

Tags: node.js, express, x-frame-options

In my express app, running on dev.example.com,  I have this line:

```
// on my own domain: dev.example.com on port 80
server.use(helmet.xframe('allow-from', 'http://example.com'));
...
server.get('/content', function(req, res) { .... });
```

and on another express app running on example.com:9000 , I have the page (index) in iframe:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="http://dev.example.com/content" width=10 height=10></iframe>
</div>
```

However, when i go to   example.com/   there will be an error saying:

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://dev.example.com/content': 'ALLOW-FROM http://example.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.
```

I tried:

```
server.use(helmet.xframe('sameorigin'));  OR 
server.use(helmet.xframe('allow-from', 'http://example.com:9000'));
```

none of them work.   Any idea?

Comment: example.com:9000 != example.com

Comment: Also, Allow-from is supported only in Firefox and IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility